# Excel VBA: Can I simply extend a range by one?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a statement in VBA to create a Range, which then is selected and copied. After that I paste that somewhere else. But the last line is pasted without a newline, so I'd like to extend my range by one. My current statement is:

```
Set twoRange = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))
twoRange.Select
twoRange.Copy
```

What is the simplest way to extend this range one row down?

Answer (score 3):

Yes:

```
Set twoRange = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(1))
twoRange.Copy
```

You use Offset to move one more cell down.  Offset uses this format: `Offset(Rows,[columns])

You also do not need to select the range to copy the range.

Comment: you don't even need to set the range and go: `Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(1)).Copy`

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
Set twoRange = Range("A2:A" & Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row + 1)
```

which adds one to the row found by using the `xlDown` approach.